# Layover timing for connecting flights

Tags: layovers, short-connections, mumbai

I have a connecting flight from Thiruvananthapuram to Ahmedabad via Mumbai. Following are the flight details

1. Thiruvananthapuram to Mumbai 12:35 to 14:55 pm
2. Mumbai to Ahmedabad 16:05 to 17:30
   That means I'll have only 1 hr 10 min layover time. Is it sufficient to make the connection? The PNR for both flights are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've booked the itinerary as a single ticket, the airline thinks it's within minimum connecting time.  This means that, if your incoming flight is delayed, you'll be put on the next available flight free of charge, and for a major route like Mumbai-Ahmedabad these should be quite frequent.